# Can I use javax.comm library when usb/rs232 converter is used?

Tags: javax.comm

I want to transfer a number from java program which is on laptop (means there is no rs232 protocol pin is provided) to a pic microcontroller(where essentially I have to used rs232) .Therefore here I require usb /rsr232 converter.
Which Java library should I use ?
Will it work with javax.comm library?

Comment: Off topic for requesting software library.

Comment: Try it and see. Typically, the USB device will expose a serial port to the operating system, and Java should be able to communicate with it using javax.comm.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it depends on the USB/RS232 converter you are using. Most that I have used will expose the serial port as a virtual com port device on your operating system (see [page 8 of this PDF document](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_US232R-10_R-100-500.pdf)). If that's the case, `javax.comm` will work fine. If not, you will have to use a proprietary API for the hardware which should be provided by the manufacturer. If you have hardware like this, I would strongly recommend replacing it with a class-compatible USB device.